# Can I bulk Upload invitees (users) in calender Events

Tags: data-loader, event, activities, calendar

I have multiple events and I want to add many users in those events. How can I bulk upload invitees(users)
I already tried public calendar but it was not meeting up with my requirements.
Every users want those events in their calendar. So I have decided to bulk upload invitees.

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bulk upload invitees .Event relation object is used to load invitees.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm

You can load data into sandbox and then once you are confident load into production.

Enabling or disabling shared activity will have affect on booleans like is what, is invitee,so make sure you understand them

Comment: Hi @Mohith Thanks for you help but when I tried to import bulk invitees. Upload was fail with error "You cannot create an Event Relation with a child event."

Comment: Filter your event file with ischild=false .do not include child events

Comment: I did but this time I am getting "RelationId must be a contact or lead for a Who relation when isWhat is false and isParent is true.: Relation ID" but I want to add users as invitees @Mohith

Comment: relationid can be userId .use userId and load

Comment: I did but getting the same error. okay let me try again. @Mohith

Comment: Which object is your event related to?

Comment: Its a public calendar so some of the events are related to Account and some of haven't related to any object. @Mohith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36366/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-russel-baker-1).